# Debugging Stored Procedures In Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I have a similar question [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618335/unable-to-debug-sql-server-2005-stored-procedures-in-visual-studio-team-system-20)

The database is located on the server (not attached in App_data folder)

When I set breakpoints, and click Step Into Stored Procedure,
The breakpoints get disabled: the breakpoint will not currently be hit. unable to bind sql breakpoint at this time

Comment: ...have you tried the suggestions on that question?

Comment: Are you using the Visual Web Developer Express version?